# How to disable the nesting made by hue in Seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

When using `hue` parameter on barplot in Seaborn it changes the color and the position of the bars. Like the following exemple:

Plot without hue:

```py
import seaborn as sns
df = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'hue': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']}
sns.barplot(
    data = df,
    x = 'x',
    y = 'y',
)
```

Output:
[Seaborn barplot without hue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8YtO.png)

Plot with hue:

```py
df = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'hue': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']}
sns.barplot(
    data = df,
    x = 'x',
    y = 'y',
    hue = 'hue'
)
```

Output:
[Seaborn barplot with hue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j3T9.png)

So how can I make a plot with the default bar position and the colors made by `hue`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `dodge=False` fixes it for me.

```
import seaborn as sns

df = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'hue': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']}
sns.barplot(
    data = df,
    x = 'x',
    y = 'y',
    hue = 'hue',
    dodge=False 
)
```

From the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

> dodge (bool, optional) - When hue nesting is used, whether elements
> should be shifted along the categorical axis.